# Exchange Web Services - Create Tasks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, exchangewebservices

I've been trying to create some code to generate non-recurring tasks in EWS. I've followed this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dhruvkh/archive/2012/04/06/working-with-tasks-using-exchange-web-services.aspx#comments), unfortunately, the code to actually send the task wasn't presented. I then followed this [Office Dev Center link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563029(v=exchg.80).aspx) which everyone seems to reference.

However, *CreateItemType()* isn't recognised.

Here's my code so far:

```
const string o365Server = "myO365Domain";
const string targetMailId = "myemail@test.com";

var service = new ExchangeService();
var task = new Task(service);
string itemId = null;

task.Subject = "mySubject";
task.Body = new MessageBody {BodyType = BodyType.Text, Text = "my new task"};
task.StartDate = DateTime.Now;

var  createItemRequest = new CreateItemType();
createItemRequest.Items = new NonEmptyArrayOfAllItemsType();
createItemRequest.Items.Items = new ItemType[1];
createItemRequest.Items.Items[0] = task;
```

I've installed Microsoft Exchange WebServices 2.2.0 via Nuget and

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
```

I just want to be able to send tasks to individual email accounts in our O365 domain. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe that syntax is from the full web service API. Since you are working with the Managed API via NuGet, Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.createitems(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Thank you - I will take a look.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to admit that I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: You could simply use `task.Save()` in your case. Either use the managed API or the full SOAP one.

Comment: Thank you - will give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim clientTZService As ExchangeService = New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010)


    clientTZService.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(userEmail, userPass)
    clientTZService.AutodiscoverUrl(userEmail, AddressOf RedirectionCallBack)


    ' Create the task
    Dim Task1 As Task = New Task(clientTZService)
    Task1.Subject = "New Task"
    Task1.Body = New MessageBody(String.Format("test"))
    Task1.StartDate = DateTime.Now
    Dim DueDate As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day + 2)
    Task1.DueDate = DueDate

       Task1.Save(New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Tasks, "test@domain.com"))
```